# Input data into single mysql column on certain row

Tags: php, mysql

How would i insert information into a column in a mysql table where in a specific row. For example, I want to insert the word politics into the column interests in a row where name is john.

Answer (score 5):

```
mysql_query("UPDATE tableName SET interests='politics' WHERE name='john'");
```

If "politics" and "john" are php variables:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE tableName SET interests='".$interest."' WHERE name='".$name."'");
```

Further readings: [PHP MySQL Update](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_update.asp)

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE table SET interests='politics' WHERE name='john';
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add a new profile then use
**INSERT INTO Profile (name,interests)
VALUES ('john','politics');**
If you want to add 'interests' to john's profile use
**UPDATE Profile
SET interests='politics'
WHERE name='john';**

Answer (score 0):

INSERT INTO table_name
VALUES (v1,v2,v3,...);

or

INSERT INTO table_name (c1,c2,c3,...)
VALUES (v1,v2,v3,...);

Comment: Would you explain it?